# Android Geocoder class, missing Town and Postcode

Tags: android, android-maps

I have problem with geocoding on android device.

```
Geocoder c = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> l = c.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
for (Address a: l) {
    Log.i("GeocoderResult", "Locality " + a.getLocality() + " poscode " + a.getPostcode());
}
```

The Android Geocoder returns the android.location.Address object. The text returned can have city and postcode in it, but corresponding object fields may still be empty.

Geocoding with town and postcode in the text, but not in the object fields:

```
50.74967518;-1.99207054:
Address text: "17 Gough Crescent, Poole, BH17, GB"
locality = null
postcode = null
Address[addressLines=[0:"17 Gough Crescent",1:"Poole",2:"BH17",3:"UK"],feature=17,admin=Poole,sub-admin=Poole,locality=null,thoroughfare=Gough Crescent,postalCode=null,countryCode=GB,countryName=United Kingdom,hasLatitude=true,latitude=50.7498262,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-1.992054,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]
```

Geocoding with town and postcode both in the text and in the object fields:

```
50.74966423;-1.99205967
Address text: 2-6 Gough Crescent, Poole BH17, GB
locality = Poole
postalCode=BH17
Address[addressLines=[0:"2-6 Gough Crescent",1:"Poole BH17",2:"UK"],feature=2-6,admin=null,sub-admin=null,locality=Poole,thoroughfare=Gough Crescent,postalCode=BH17,countryCode=GB,countryName=United Kingdom,hasLatitude=true,latitude=50.7496887,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-1.9917892,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]
```

Are we missing something and something can be done to retrieve the missing town and postcode data using just Android Geocoder as is? Or is the only way to do this guessing which of the fields is likely to contain town data if the 'locality' is empty and trying to parse address text for postcode?